# Azure Uploading VHD Fail

Tags: azure, vhd

I have a bizspark account to azure and i am trying to upload my MS Server 2003 VHD to a Storage/blob in order to access it as a VM.

I used disk2vhd to make the vhd file which is 68Gb.

Then i created a storage with Geo-replication, and added a container.

After that through the azure powershell i did the following

Get the publishing settings :  `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`

Import them on azure account:  `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile C:\path`

Upload the vhd:

```
Add-AzureVhd -Destination http://pythia.blob.core.windows.net/pythia/OldPythia -LocalFilePath C:\path\server2003.vhd`
```

MD5 is calculated correctly but the i got an error.

here are the results:

> MD5 hash is being calculated for the file  C:\server2003.vhd MD5 hash
>   calculation is completed. Elapsed time for the operation: 00:22:59
>   Creating new page blob... Upload failed with exceptions: Elapsed time
>   for upload: 00:10:15

These are all the steps i follow. What should i do?

Comment: Try [Blob Transfer utility](http://blobtransferutility.codeplex.com/) its a great app.  The only problem you'll have w/ VHD's is that they need to go up as page blobs instead of block blobs.  That can be changed easily in code tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the node.js tools:

1. Install [node.js](http://nodejs.org)
2. Follow instructions [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/install-and-configure-cli/)
3. azure vm disk upload

After this I was able to manually create a VM in the management console using the disk I uploaded.